# Working with processes in linux with C

Tags: c, linux, process, pid

I got used to writing script in bash when working with linux but I'm a novice when it comes to writing scripts for linux in C.

For assignment I have to work with processes. Nothing hard for an experienced programmer for I only have to loop trough all processes in a certain directory and get the basic information.

More precisely, I receive in a first argument a dir where processes are located(default /proc/) then i have to print name, PID, PPID, processor state(S/R), number of open files and number of threads for that process. This has to be done for all processes located in given dir, but if a second argument is present(switch -s PID) you only print process information for processes that are located in the subtree of the received PID. Last argument(p/n/t) dictates what print order you have to choose. p is sorted by PID, i is sorted by the name of the process and t is sorted by the number of threads

print format `printf("%10s %5s %5s %2s %3s %3s\n", "name", "PID", "PPID", "state", "Files", "Threads");`

Now i'm not asking you to write everything instead of me so i give zero effort, i would just like to be sent on the right track, how to step up to the problem, a few examples, explanations,...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following:

- First establish which directory you are searching, by default `/proc`
- Use `opendir` to obtain a handle to `/proc`
- Use `readdir` to obtain a `dirent` for every entity inside `/proc`

  - Ignore entities that are not directories or whose names aren't strictly numeric
- At this point you have only directories of processes
- For each name use `opendir` again. Inside each directory the interesting things for you are `stat`, and maybe the subdirectory `fd`

And of course there are plenty of resources:

- [`readdir` example](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html)
- [`proc` layout](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html)